# Selecting the first and second node in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Given the following structure, how to copy the first and the second nodes with all their elements from the document based on the predicate in XSLT:

```
<list>
  <slot>xx</slot>
   <data>
       <name>xxx</name>
       <age>xxx</age>  
   </data>      
   <data>
       <name>xxx</name>
       <age>xxx</age>  
   </data> 
   <data>
       <name>xxx</name>
       <age>xxx</age>  
   </data> 
</list> 
<list>
  <slot>xx</slot>
   <data>
       <name>xxx</name>
       <age>xxx</age>  
   </data> 
   <data>
       <name>xxx</name>
       <age>xxx</age>  
   </data> 
   <data>
       <name>xxx</name>
       <age>xxx</age>  
   </data> 
</list>
```

How to select the first and the second occurence of data (without the data element itself, only name, age) from the list, where the slot is equal to a different variable, i.e the first list has the `slot=02`, but I need the data from the second list, where the `slot=01`. But it does not really matter the order of the list by a slot as long as `slot=$slotvariable`.

I tried the following statement, but it did not produce any results:

```
<xsl:element name="{'Lastdata'}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="list/data[position()=1 and slot = $slotvariable]" />
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="{'prevdata'}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="list/data[position()=2 and slot = $slotvariable]" />
</xsl:element>
```

Any working suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Things that are missing from this question: 1) An XML sample that actually matches your explanations instead of containing all `xxxxx`. 2) The output as you imagine it. Please add these things (you can edit your question) so people are not forced to guess in their answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then:

```
<Lastdata>
  <xsl:copy-of select="list[slot=$slotvariable]/data[1]/*" />
</Lastdata>
<prevdata>
  <xsl:copy-of select="list[slot=$slotvariable]/data[2]/*" />
<prevdata>
```

Hints:

- Don't use `<xsl:element>` unless you have a dynamic name based on an expression.
- `[1]` is a shorthand for `[position() = 1]`

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="slot" select="'slot1'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/lists/list">
        <xsl:copy-of select="data[../slot=$slot][position()&lt;3]/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this source:

```
<lists>
    <list>
      <slot>slot1</slot>
       <data>
           <name>George</name>
           <age>7</age>  
       </data> 
       <data>
           <name>Bob</name>
           <age>22</age>  
       </data> 
       <data>
           <name>James</name>
           <age>77</age>  
       </data> 
    </list> 
    <list>
      <slot>slot2</slot>
       <data>
           <name>Wendy</name>
           <age>25</age>  
       </data> 
    </list> 
</lists>
```

Produces the following result:

```
<name>George</name>
<age>7</age>
<name>Bob</name>
<age>22</age>
```

Comment: `data[../slot[1]=$slot]` is equivalent to `data[slot=$slot]`, and I don't think you can use variables in match expressions.

Comment: @Tomalak - Yup. I'd already changed that before I saw your comment.

Comment: Next time when you write "produces the following output", also check if it actually does. ;-) *(There is still a variable in your match expression.)*

Comment: @Tomalek - What? I did. That's exactly what it outputs in Firefox. The variable causes no problems. I copy/pasted the result.

Comment: Check with another tool and you will get an error. Variables are not supported in match expressions in XSLT 1.0. Try here for example: http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=xslt

Comment: Let me be more specific, since the solution from Tomalak did not work, and i would not like to use another template, it is already inside of couple.

Comment: @Tomalek - Good to know. I definitely tested, but was tricked by a non-compliant XSLT processor.

Comment: I'll update with a far simpler solution that produces the same result, even though it's not clear exactly what's expected. For one thing, my solution treats the first and second occurrence the same. They are not wrapped in different tags.