# XSLT: How to insert edited elements in specific position in an XML document

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to making changes in an XML document and I'm having trouble inserting a group of elements - which are lightly edited with in XSLT - in  specific position. so here we go, this is XML:

```mxml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<h1:DocumentSet xmlns:h1="http://www.startext.de/HiDA/DefService/XMLSchema">
  <h1:ContentInfo>
    <h1:Format>HIDA-DOC1-XML</h1:Format>
    <h1:CreationDate>21.04.2016 14:17:30:042</h1:CreationDate>
  </h1:ContentInfo> 
<h1:Document DocKey="obj     00000003" FieldsCount="286">
    <h1:Block Type="obj" CreationDate="03.02.2014 11:43:26" CreatorID="Admin" ChangeDate="21.01.2015 10:29:20" ChangerID="Admin" OwnerID="Admin" FieldsCount="220">
      <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="00000003"/>
      <h1:Field Type="9920" Value="1931.03.07"/>
      <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="TWS">
        <h1:Field Type="2800"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="München"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2862" Value="unbekannt"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2930" Value="Fotoabteilung"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2950" Value="TWS_FGL00001"/>
        <h1:Field Type="907d" Value="No. 231"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="5108" Value="München">
        <h1:Field Type="5110" Value="Theater unbekannt"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob30">
        <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannt"/>
        <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Fotograf/in, Atelier"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob30">
        <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannt"/>
        <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Verlag"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob30">
        <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="Grillparzer, Franz"/>
        <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Autor/in"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob30">
        <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="Böhm, Karl Hans"/>
        <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Regie"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob30">
        <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="Linnebach, Adolf"/>
        <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Bühnenbild"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="Ahnfrau, Die"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5220" Value="Fotografie"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5226" Value="Negativ"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="Glasplattennegativ"/>
      <h1:Field Type="agZeit"/>
      <h1:Field Type="agThema"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5360" Value="18x13"/>
      <h1:Field Type="55th" Value="Zäpfel, Armand"/>
      <h1:Field Type="8450">
        <h1:Field Type="8470"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8540" Value="F:\Glasplattennegative\JPEG\TWS_FGL00001"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8555" Value="F:\Glasplattennegative\JPEG\TWS_FGL_00001"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8555mf" Value="F:\Glasplattennegative\JPEG\TWS_FGL_00001"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e01" Value="TWS_FGL00001.jpg"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e02" Value="3347"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e03" Value="4598"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e04" Value="24"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e05" Value="355049"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e06" Value="Perfection V700/V750"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e07" Value="EPSON"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e08" Value="2014:02:06 14:16:13"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="9990" Value="Fritz Basil als Graf von Borotin&#x3b; Midi Scheinpflug als Berta, seine Tochter&#x3b; Armand Zäpfel als Jaromir&#x3b; Wolf von Strobl als Boleslav&#x3b; Arnulf Schröder als Günther, Kastellan&#x3b; Albert Lippert als Ein Hauptmann&#x3b; Albert Wisheu als Ein Soldat"/>
    </h1:Block>
</h1:Document>
</h1:DocumentSet>`
```

And here is my XSLT:

```mxml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:h1="http://www.startext.de/HiDA/DefService/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.startext.de/HiDA/DefService/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template name="alles" match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='9920']">
        <h1:Field Type="5060" Value="Aufnahme">
            <h1:Field Type="5064" Value="{@Value}"/>
        </h1:Field>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='ob28']">
        <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="Verwalter">
            <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="Köln"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2900" Value="{@Value}"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='2930']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='2950']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='907d']"/>
        </h1:Field>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='5108']">
        <h1:Field Type="ob26" Value="Aufnahmeort">
            <h1:Field Type="2664" Value="{@Value}"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2690" Value="Theater"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2700" Value="{.//Field/@Value}"/>
        </h1:Field>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='ob30']"/>

    <!--   To Do: here is my problem! i want it to appear exact same position, where the first ob30 in xml starts
    <xsl:template match=".//Block">
            <xsl:call-template name="alles"/>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//Field[@Type='ob30']">
                <xsl:if test="position()= 1">
                <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3100']"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3475']"/>
                </h1:Field>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position()= 3">
                    <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Darstellung">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3100']"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3475']"/>
                        <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
                    </h1:Field>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position()= 4 or position()= 5">
                    <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Inszenierung">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3100']"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3475']"/>
                    </h1:Field>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
    -->

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='5226']">
            <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="{@Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='5230']">
        <h1:Field Type="5240" Value="{@Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='9990']">
        <h1:Field Type="599a" Value="Werkkommentar">
            <h1:Field Type="599e" Value="{@Value}"/>
            <h1:Field Type="599n" Value="P,N"/>
        </h1:Field>
        <h1:Field Type="9902" Value="TWS"/>
        <h1:Field Type="9904" Value="P,N"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i want the edited elements with attribute "ob30" to appear exact same position, where the first ob30 in xml starts. the elements with ob30 attribute appears as sibling elements of "Block" element. I have no idea how to fix it. Have you a practical solution for this?

Edit: here, i add the desired output:

```mxml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:h1="http://www.startext.de/HiDA/DefService/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.startext.de/HiDA/DefService/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />

 <h1:DocumentSet xmlns:h1="http://www.startext.de/HiDA/DefService/XMLSchema">
  <h1:ContentInfo>
    <h1:Format>HIDA-DOC1-XML</h1:Format>
    <h1:CreationDate>09.06.2015 09:31:15:408</h1:CreationDate>
  </h1:ContentInfo>
  <h1:Document DocKey="obj     40020000">
    <h1:Block Type="obj" CreationDate="03.02.2014 11:43:26" CreatorID="Admin" ChangeDate="07.02.2014 13:29:02" ChangerID="Admin" OwnerID="Admin">
      <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="40020000"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5060" Value="Aufnahme">
        <h1:Field Type="5064" Value="1931.03.07"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="Verwalter">
        <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="Köln"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2900" Value="Theaterwissenschaftliche Sammlung, Universität zu Köln"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2930" Value="Fotoabteilung"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2940" Value="München"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2950" Value="TWS_FGL00001"/>
        <h1:Field Type="907d" Value="No. 231"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob26" Value="Aufnahmeort">
        <h1:Field Type="2664" Value="München"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2690" Value="Theater"/>
        <h1:Field Type="2700" Value="unbekanntes Theater"/>
      </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
        <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannter Fotograf"/>
        <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Fotograf"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="5007" Value="Darstellung">
        <h1:Field Type="5009" Value="Grillparzer, Franz"/>
        <h1:Field Type="5010" Value="Schauspiel"/>
        <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
        <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="Böhm, Karl Hans"/>
        <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Regisseur"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
        <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="Linnebach, Adolf"/>
        <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Bühnenbildner"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="Die Ahnfrau"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5220" Value="Fotografie"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="Negativ"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5240" Value="Glasplattennegativ"/>
      <h1:Field Type="5360" Value="18x13"/>
      <h1:Field Type="55th" Value="unbekannt"/>
      <h1:Field Type="8450" Value="digitale Reproduktion">
        <h1:Field Type="8540" Value="TWS_FGL00001"/>
         <h1:Field Type="8494" Value="1931.03.07"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8555" Value="F:\Glasplattennegative\JPEG\TWS_FGL_00001"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8555mf" Value="F:\Glasplattennegative\JPEG\TWS_FGL_00001"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e01" Value="TWS_FGL00001.jpg"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e02" Value="3347"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e03" Value="4598"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e04" Value="24"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e05" Value="355049"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e06" Value="Perfection V700/V750"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e07" Value="EPSON"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8e08" Value="2014:02:06 14:16:13"/>
      </h1:Field>
      <h1:Field Type="599a" Value="Werkkommentar">
        <h1:Field Type="599e" Value="Fritz Basil als Graf von Borotin&#x3b; Midi Scheinpflug als Berta, seine Tochter&#x3b; Armand Zäpfel als Jaromir&#x3b; Wolf von Strobl als Boleslav&#x3b; Arnulf Schröder als Günther, Kastellan&#x3b; Albert Lippert als Ein Hauptmann&#x3b; Albert Wisheu als Ein Soldat"/>
        <h1:Field Type="599n" Value="P,N"/>
        </h1:Field>
          <h1:Field Type="9902" Value="TWS"/>
      <h1:Field Type="9904" Value="P,N"/>
    </h1:Block>
</h1:Document>
</h1:DocumentSet>
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you want to create for the input snippet you have shown? I am not sure which problem you have, if you want to transform the first `Field[@Type='ob30']` then write a template `match="Field[@Type='ob30'][1]"` if you want to transform the third then write a template `match="Field[@Type='ob30'][3]"` and so on.

Comment: if i use this template, I become a syntax error "Unexpected token "]" beyond end of expression". because of that reason, i had to count the position to determine the "ob30".  i`ll edit my question to add the output.

Comment: If you need help with a syntax error then please post a minimal but complete stylesheet allowing others to reproduce the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting the first and second node in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366114/selecting-the-first-and-second-node-in-xslt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try along the following lines:

```
<xsl:template match="Field[@Type='ob30']"/>

<xsl:template match="Field[@Type='ob30'][1]" priority="5">
    <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3100']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3475']"/>
    </h1:Field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field[@Type='ob30'][3]" priority="5">
    <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Darstellung">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3100']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3475']"/>
        <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
    </h1:Field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field[@Type='ob30'][position() = (4, 5)]" priority="5">
    <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Inszenierung">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3100']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Field[@Type='3475']"/>
    </h1:Field>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i think i mistyped something while i was trying to use match="Field[@Type='ob30'][1]"